# get same permission screen every time when login with facebook app installed in the iOS device

Tags: objective-c, facebook, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK v3.5 for my app, I found that if I installed the facebook app and was not logged into the iOS device (Settings > facebook), then if I was logged into my app for the first time, it works fine: it will switch to the facebook app's login view and show some permissions with a "OK" and a "cancel" button. but after I was logged into my app and logged out and logged in again, the same permission screen in the facebook app will still be shown. I think the expected behavior is that when log in for the second time we should not see that permission screen since we have already granted these in the first time log in.

The same thing happens in the sample project "Scrumptious" in the FB SDK v3.5. Does someone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the behavior is working as intended.  Basically, the semantic here is that the user has logged out, so it is appropriate to ask them to confirm to log in again. Specifically the logout code in the sample (and in most apps) is to clear the token cache on the device, so the next time the app is asking for a new token.

You are right that once a user has granted permissions (and until they revoke them), the Facebook servers do know this. As a result there is a slightly nuanced flow in the login screen (you can see this by granting publish to scrumptious, and then the next time you request post it will be something akin to "you've already granted this permission").

So, you could technically not clear the token cache but then why bother with a log out option.

Hope that helps.